# Cassandra store and query dynamic (user defined) data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We've been looking into using Cassandra to store some of the larger data in a multi-tenant system we are building. The decision to use Cassandra is mostly to do with scaling capabilities and performance when working with large data sets, but I am not sure whether what we're looking for is possible in Cassandra, so I'm hoping someone has some clues as to whether (and how) this could be done:

We are looking for a way to provide our users to first define their own Entity types then define fields in those entities (and field types). Once they've defined this, their data (that matches the definitions they just created) could be imported, stored and most importantly queried by pretty much any field they defined.

So for instance, we may have one user who defines an Airplane, which has the manufacturer name, model, tail number, year of production, etc...

Their data will, then, contain those fields, be searchable and sortable by those fields, etc..

Another user may decide to define a Boat, which can then have different fields, which should be also sortable and searchable by content.

Because of the possible number of entries - the typical relational approach is unlikely to yield adequate performance, so we're looking at a noSQL approach.

Is this something that could be done in C*? Or are there any other suggestions in terms of a storage engine that would offer best flexibility?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two important points in your requirements

- Dynamic typing/schemaless data: Cassandra defines how data is structured like a relational database. Yet you can use columns of complex type: map...
- Query by any field: Cassandra requires each query to provide the partition id. Cassandra data model is driven by querying, if you don't know your queries in advance, you won't be able to design the appropriate model, and you won't be able to query it.

I advise you to have look at Elasticsearch. 
Then, if you have to use Cassandra for some other reason, then I advise you to look a DataStax Enterprise edition of Cassandra which integrates with SolR and Spark: both will give you extra querying capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We don't *have* to use Cassandra, we are looking for an optimal solution that covers our requirements.